# Loading a plugin into an AppDomain and calling the constructor

Tags: c#, plugins, parameters, constructor, appdomain

As you can tell by the title, I'm trying to load a plugin into a new AppDomain. I want to call the constructor when that happens.
Normally this wouldn't be a problem but the constructor takes a parameter. In this case, it's a class that uses a bunch of other classes too.

```
AppDomain domain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("Plugins");
object inst = Activator.CreateInstance(domain, "ircplugin", "eIRCBot.Plugin", false, BindingFlags.Default, null, new object[] { ircinstance }, null, null);
```

If I do this, it gives me the following exception:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Type 'IRCLib.IrcInstance' in assembly 'IRCLib, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' is not marked as serializable.
```

How do I solve this? I can't go and make all of the classes serializable because it also uses some of .net's classes like tcpclient. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Which line of code causes the exception?

Comment: The second line (i.e. Activator.CreateInstance......)